# Custom Seekbar View implementation

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I am trying to implement a similar effect to this `SeekBar`:

[HUMSlider for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/humslider)

for an Android Application.

I know that I have to implement it using `Canvas`, but I am quite new to this.

I tried implementing a `View` for the graduation unit and then adding multiple instances from it in a `ViewGroup`.  But I just can't get it right.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First approach would be to extend `SeekBar` class, overriding the drawing methods like `onDraw(Canvas canvas)`.

Comment: I see, can you provide a link to a sample implementation, please.